# Is it against German law to oppose the existence of the state of Israel?

Tags: germany, freedom-of-speech

If in the German jurisdiction a person, without inciting violence, states in writing or in speech that they are opposed to the existence of the state of Israel and advocates that other people should also be so opposed, are they breaking German law?

I am interested in two cases: first, the general case (has the person committed a crime?); second, the case of a German civil servant (can or must their employer discipline them or even sack them in response to their action?)

Comment: Did you find anything that would suggest it?

Comment: You can't quite oppose the existence of the state of Israel without advocating some major amount of violence, since the non-existence of that state implies massacring millions of Jews living there. But if you have any specific case in mind, you should post the details.

Comment: @gnasher729 while I agree that the citizens of Israel would probably oppose the dissolution of that state it is theoretically possible that that (or any) state could be dissolved peacefully.

Comment: @unor - What made me think it might be so was the unpublicised but clarified by email policy of a German company that owns a chat website. Some of their policies are simply German law, but I am not sure about this one. They won't say whether or not they believe they are simply seeking to ensure that German law isn't broken. I don't want to name them because that wouldn't help with the answer and I'd be interested in this question whatever made me think of it.

Comment: @DaleM: Israel's neighbours have tried for 50+ years to dissolve the state most unpeacefully.

Comment: There have been 39 years of peace with Egypt, 23 with Jordan, and no conflicts between Israel and either of its other two neighbours for many years, let alone any effort by either of those states to dissolve Israel violently. Even if your premise were true, which it is not, it would not support the conclusion that calling for a peaceful end to the state of Israel is impossible. Do you have a contribution to make on the question of German law that is posed here?

Answer (score 6):

## General case - legal or not?

It is hard to prove a negative - however, as far as I can see:

**It is not illegal to state your opinion that the existence of the state of Israel is unjustified, or that the state should be dissolved.**

Such a position would be considered outrageous by most Germans, in particular it is against the stated position of pretty much all political parties, except for the extreme right or left, and of most other organizations. It is not, however, illegal.

In general, the dissolution of a state is not in itself illegal according to national or international law, as long as it happens voluntarily. There are some precedents: For example, during the German Reunification of 1989, the German Democratic Republic (East Germany) acceded to the Federal Republic of Germany (West Germany) under the (old) Article 23 of the *Grundgesetz*. One could argue that the German Democratic Republic effectively dissolved itself by that accession.

What *would* probably be illegal would be to call for a violent end of the state of Israel, or even for a war. The relevant laws:

- [§130 Strafgesetzbuch](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__130.html) -- *[Volksverhetzung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volksverhetzung)* (incitement to hatred)
- [§13 Völkerstrafgesetzbuch](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/vstgb/__13.html) -- *[Angriffskrieg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angriffskrieg)* (war of aggression)
- and, only applicable to the state: [Art. 26 Grundgesetz](https://dejure.org/gesetze/GG/26.html) -- *[Angriffskrieg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angriffskrieg)* (war of aggression)

## Special case - civil servants

Civil servants are citizens, too, so mostly the same laws apply to them. However, for civil servants specifically there are higher requirements when it comes to respect for the German constitution, specifically for the "[*freiheitliche demokratische Grundordnung*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiheitliche_demokratische_Grundordnung)" (literally: "basic free and democratic order"). That means that opinions which are "extremist" but not illegal may not be tolerated.

Applicable laws/regulations:

- [§7 Beamtenstatusgesetz](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/beamtstg/__7.html)
- [§9 Richtergesetz](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/drig/__9.html)
- §3 of the [Tarifvertrag der Länder (TV-L)](http://www.tdl-online.de/fileadmin/downloads/rechte_Navigation/A._TV-L__2011_/01_Tarifvertrag/TV-L__i_d_F__des_%C3%84TV_Nr__9_VT.pdf)

As far as I can see, the rules for whether something violates these rules would be similar as above.

---

Note that there are even some Israelis who think that the state of Israel should not exist, at least not in its present form, so such a position is not totally unthinkable. The Wikipedia articles [Right to exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_exist) and [Existenzrecht Israels](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existenzrecht_Israels) (German) give a good overview.

Comment: To the downvoter: I'd appreciate a comment explaining what is wrong with the answer - I researched it and tried to name the applicable laws.

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful and well researched answer on the general case. I tried to upvote but at the moment I only have 11 points. On the specific case of civil servants, though, I was wondering whether such advocacy might get a civil servant into trouble under the Berufsverbot? If you can answer on that too, I will accept this answer.

Comment: @tell: I'll try to dig up something on civil servants.

Comment: There are still many who advocate a one-state secular-and-democratic Palestinian solution, to be achieved non-violently, such as [these people](http://www.1not2.org). They write that "(t)he Constitution (of the Republic of Palestine) will be founded on the principle that all people who live in historic Palestine as well as Palestinian refugees who realise their right of return will have equality of citizenship and equality of stake." I would like to know whether a German civil servant who publicly supported this group, for example, could find himself in legal or employment trouble.

Comment: @tell: I edited to address civil servants. As to the page you link: I don't know the movement, so cannot comment on it. You could try applying the criteria I gave.

Comment: I don’t think _basic_ qualifies as a literal translation of _freiheitlich_; but apart from that, a good answer.

Comment: @chirlu: "basic" is not meant as a translation of _freiheitlich_, but of the _Grund_ in _Grundordnung_.  I edited to complete the translation.

Comment: You should remove the reference to § 26 StGB. This does not apply here. This regulation is for incitement, which means it is accessory. In other words: § 26 StGB alone does not lead to punishment. What it says is that if someone commits a crime, the instigator will be punished according to the same law. That means that there has to be another crime that has to be committed for § 26 StGB to have an effect.

Comment: Also, the other 26, Art. 26 GG does not apply here. Affected by the basic law is the state, not the citicens. As a person you can not "break" Art. 26 GG. Its target are the brances of the state (legislative, executive, judiciary), which have to stand down from aggression and provide the necessary legal and administrative environment to make it impossible. What would apply here is rather § 13 VStGB.

Comment: @Sefe: Yes, you're right, thank you. I edited my answer. I left Art. 26 GG in, because it is still relevant - it means that even if you happen to be the chancellor, you  must not plan an attack against Israel (or any other country).

Comment: Better now, even though systematically, Art. 26 GG still does not quite fit here, since it obliges authorities, not persons to provide a punishment fur such actions (hence § 13 VStGB). You can not punish individuals (even not in their role as public authorities) directly by that law. But it's the same ballpark.